# display diagonal size conflict in various android device

Tags: android, screen

I am working to get device display diagonal length. I used the formula, diagonal = width* width + height* height. To achieve this I use below code.

```
    DisplayInfo aDisplayInfo = new DisplayInfo();
    DecimalFormat twoDecimalForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    aDisplayInfo.widthInch = (dm.widthPixels * dm.density) / (dm.xdpi * 2);
    aDisplayInfo.heightInch = ((dm.heightPixels * dm.density) / (dm.ydpi * 2));
    aDisplayInfo.widthPix = dm.widthPixels;
    aDisplayInfo.heightPix = dm.heightPixels;

    // approaach 1
    aDisplayInfo.diagonalInch = twoDecimalForm.format(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(
            aDisplayInfo.widthInch, 2)
            + Math.pow(aDisplayInfo.heightInch, 2)));
```

After running this code I found out different results in different devices. Like:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 = 4.8 inches (correct)
- HTC One X = 6.8 inches (wrong) [ will be 4.7 inches]

What's wrong with this code? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
aDisplayInfo.widthInch = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;
aDisplayInfo.heightInch = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;
```

`widthPixels`/`heightPixels` should be the physical pixel count. `xdpi`/`ydpi` should be pixels per inch. You shouldn't need to do any scaling on these values.

Comment: after checking i will reply